# Angular: Getting a module not found error only when building for prod

Tags: angular, error-handling

**Update**

After updating to Angular v4, I get the following error (i have not changed the code).

```
ERROR in Invalid provider for ErrorHandler in /Users/otusweb/Documents/KeynoteTweet/web/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts. useClass cannot be null.
       Usually it happens when:
       1. There's a circular dependency (might be caused by using index.ts (barrel) files).
       2. Class was used before it was declared. Use forwardRef in this case.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Users/otusweb/Documents/KeynoteTweet/web/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

**Original question**

I'm trying to set a custom global error handler in my angular 2 app to send those to rollbar. I followed https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3138-creating-a-custom-errorhandler-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm and https://netbasal.com/angular-2-custom-exception-handler-1bcbc45c3230

When I run in dev mode, everything works great. Once I build for prod (ng build --prod) I get the following error in the browser:

```
Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
```

Here is the code:
error-handling.ts

```
import { RollbarService } from  'angular-rollbar/lib';
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export default class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  private rollbar:RollbarService;

  constructor(rollbar: RollbarService) {
    // The true paramter tells Angular to rethrow exceptions, so operations like 'bootstrap' will result in an error
    // when an error happens. If we do not rethrow, bootstrap will always succeed.
    super(true);

    this.rollbar = rollbar;
  }

  handleError( error: any ) : void {
    if(!isDevMode()) 
    {
    // send the error to the server
    this.rollbar.error(error.message, error);
    }
    else
    {
    console.log("skipping rollbar");
    }

    // delegate to the default handler
    super.handleError(error); 
  }
}
```

and app.module (without the imports)

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      PresentationsComponent,
      PresentationDetailComponent,
      SlideDetailComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [ 
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      InlineEditorModule,
      RollbarModule.forRoot({
        accessToken: 'xxxxxtokenxxxx',
      }),
      NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler },
    PresentationService,
    SlideService,
    Auth,
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [ Http, RequestOptions ]
    },
  AuthGuard,
  LoggedOutGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue, the import in the app module for my custom error handler was missing the braces...

```
import  CustomErrorHandler  from './error-handling';
```

Instead of

```
import { CustomErrorHandler } from './error-handling';
```

Comment: Angular 8.0.0, `ng build --prod` was not working because of this :) thank you man

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue but adding the braces generated another error, in addition to adding the braces, I had to remove the 'default' in error-handling.ts:

Change:

```
 @Injectable()
 export default class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
```

by:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class CustomErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
```

And add the braces:

```
import { CustomErrorHandler } from './error-handling';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your child modules cannot find `BrowserModule`, try to add it to exports like:

```
exports: [
  BrowserModule,
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried it and it did not work